# SQL Grouping columns by row

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Struggling with the SQL query to convert the data I have into the required format. I have an event log for machines and would like to associate the start and stop time and event outcome in the same row.
I am unable to use LAG due to the version of SQLServer. Any help appreciated.

current dataset:

```
+----------+----------+------------+------------------------------+---------------------+
| MACHINE  | EVENT_ID | EVENT_CODE |           DATE_TIME          | EVENT_DESCRIPTOR    |
+----------+----------+------------+------------------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 1        | 1          | 2020-08-06 14:59:26          | SCAN : START : z1 : |
| 1        | 2        | 6          | 2020-08-06 15:00:18          | SCAN : END : z1 :   |
| 1        | 3        | 1          | 2020-08-06 15:00:45          | SCAN : START : z1 : |
| 1        | 4        | 5          | 2020-08-06 15:01:54          | SCAN : ABORT : z1 : |
| 2        | 5        | 1          | 2020-08-06 15:02:15          | SCAN : START : z1 : |
| 2        | 6        | 6          | 2020-08-06 15:05:07          | SCAN : END : z1 :   |
| 1        | 7        | 1          | 2020-08-06 15:05:13          | NEST : START : z1 : |
| 1        | 8        | 6          | 2020-08-06 15:05:22          | NEST : END : z1 :   |
| 1        | 9        | 1          | 2020-08-06 15:07:17          | CUT : START : z1 :  |
| 1        | 10       | 6          | 2020-08-06 15:10:40          | CUT : END : z1 :    |
+----------+----------+------------+------------------------------+---------------------+
```

The outcome I am trying to achieve:

```
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
| Machine  | SCAN:START:Z1 _TIME          | SCAN:STOP_OR_ABORT:Z1 _TIME  | OUTCOME  |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
| 1        | Thu Aug 06 14:59:26 BST 2020 | 2020-08-06 15:00:18          | END      |
| 1        | Thu Aug 06 15:00:45 BST 2020 | 2020-08-06 15:01:54          | ABORT    |
| 1        | Thu Aug 06 15:02:15 BST 2020 | 2020-08-06 15:05:07          | END      |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: *"I am unable to use LAG due the version of SQLServer."* That means you're using SQL Sever 2008 or prior. I strongly recommend you get the upgrade path started, as that means you're using a completely unsupported version of SQL Server.

Comment: That sample data doesn't make any sense as it is either. Is your data really a single `varchar` value as your data appears to be? If so, the first step is fixing that and normalising it. Also, if you can't use `LAG`, then use a self referencing join with `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: What happened to Event ID 7 and 8? They aren't in your expected results.

Comment: I'm guessing he only wants the SCAN events, but in that case he shouldn't include Event_ID 9 and 10 either.

Comment: Yes, I never meant to include event 9 and 10. I plan to query the different event descriptors separately as there are many and this was just a sample of the data. Updated outcome to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the starting events and join them the ending events as subqueries, in the form, for example, of an outer apply.

```
select L1.Machine, L1.date_time as Start, L2.datetime as Stop_Or_Abort,
       case L2.Event_Id when 5 then 'ABORT' when 6 then 'END' end as Outcome
from MyLogs L1 
     outer apply (select top 1 L2.date_time, L2.Event_Code
                  from MyLogs L2
                  where L2.Machine = L1.Machine and                         
                        L2.Event_ID > L1.Event_ID and
                        L2.Event_Code in (5, 6) 
                  order by L2.Event_ID) as L2
where L1.Event_Descriptor Like 'SCAN%' and
      L1.Event_Code = 1
```

Comment: I think you are missing and End in your case clause.

Comment: thanks Marc with END in place I managed to successfully use this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Outer Apply to get the next record after the start, filtering only the SCAN events.

```
Select  Machine = L.MACHINE,
        [SCAN:START:Z1 _TIME] =  L.DATE_TIME,
        [SCAN:STOP_OR_ABORT:Z1 _TIME] = E.DATE_TIME,
        Outcome = Case  when E.EVENT_CODE = 5 then 'ABORT'
                            when E.EVENT_CODE = 6 then 'END'
                End
From Logs L
Outer Apply
(
    Select top 1    L1.DATE_TIME,
                    L1.EVENT_CODE
    From Logs L1
    where   L1.MACHINE = L.MACHINE and
            L1.EVENT_CODE in (5, 6) and
            L1.DATE_TIME > L.DATE_TIME
    order by EVENT_ID
) E
where L.EVENT_CODE = 1
and L.EVENT_DESCRIPTOR like 'SCAN%'
```

Comment: Thanks iceblade managed to get this working. Although the query ran slowly at around 9s vs 0.034 for Marcs.

Comment: @Storm2015 our queries are basically the same, they are going to use the exact same execution plan. The time difference that you have seen has probably been an slower run at the first try, and a faster run on the second query, due to using data already on cache.

Comment: @MarcGuillot I tried multi runs but always got results from 6-10 sec

Comment: @Storm2015 that's curious, the only real difference between our queries is the way we have built the CASE construction (simple vs searched cases). I wouldn't have expected to have such an impact.

Comment: It could be because of the comparison inside the Outer Apply, In my case I'm getting the next record based on L1.DATE_TIME > L.DATE_TIME, in Marc's answer the comparison is by L2.Event_ID > L1.Event_ID, that column is probably indexed. Therefore, @MarcGuillot has the better answer. :-)